# Is it possible to destructure image folder files in React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm creating a react app. I have an image folder with a few files. In order for React to render the image I have to import it like I import other modules. Something like this:

[image: image import into a Component]

What I want to do is import the whole image folder, and then find a way to access each file in my Component. for example:

```
import img from '.../img'
```

In my JSX, I want to be able to access each of the files from the imported image folder.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: You can put the images in a public folder and access them through a URL, you don't have to  import them into the application

Answer (score 3):

You still need to import those images in some place. For cleaner syntax in your main component file, I will group the image files in 1 file

```
//grouping images in one module. Let's say it is image.js

import imageA from <your-patha>
import imageB from <your-pathb>
import imageC from <your-pathc>

export default {
   imgA: imageA, 
   imgB: imageB, 
   imgC: imageC
}
```

```
//Home component
import Images from '<image.js path>'

const Home = () => {
    return (
      <img src={Images.imgA} //...other props  />
    )
}
```

Comment: What @Sam is also ok. If there is a few images, you can put it into the public folder. When you have many of images, you may need to consider the application production problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is you can put all your images in the public folder and refer like below on component.

```
<img src="/image.jpg" alt="image" />
```